# monthly resampling pandas with specific start day

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a pandas DataFrame with random dates and random integers values and I want to resample it by month and compute the average value of integers. This can be done with the following code:

```
def random_dates(start='2018-01-01', end='2019-01-01', n=300):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01')

dates = random_dates(start, end)
ints = np.random.randint(100, size=300)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': dates, 'Integers': ints})

print(df.resample('M', on='Month').mean())
```

The thing is that the resampled months always starts from day one and I want all months to start from day 15. I'm using pandas 1.1.4 and I've tried using `origin='15/01/2018'` or `offset='15'` and none of them works with `'M'` resample rule (they do work when I use `30D` but it is of no use). I've also tried to use `'2SM'`but it also doesn't work.

So my question is if is there a way of changing the resample rule or I will have to add an offset in my data?

Comment: Do you want all months to start from day 15 or just month 1?

Comment: @kate-melnykova, I want all months starting from day 15. I edited it on my question to be more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the source DataFrame is:

```
       Month  Amount
0 2020-05-05       1
1 2020-05-14       1
2 2020-05-15      10
3 2020-05-20      10
4 2020-05-30      10
5 2020-06-15      20
6 2020-06-20      20
```

To compute your "shifted" resample, first shift *Month* column so that
the 15-th day of month becomes the 1-st:

```
df.Month = df.Month - pd.Timedelta('14D')
```

and then resample:

```
res = df.resample('M', on='Month').mean()
```

The result is:

```
            Amount
Month             
2020-04-30       1
2020-05-31      10
2020-06-30      20
```

If you want, change dates in the index to month periods:

```
res.index = res.index.to_period('M')
```

Then the result will be:

```
         Amount
Month          
2020-04       1
2020-05      10
2020-06      20
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It certainly solves the problem, thus I'm upvotting it, but I wish there was a way of doing it without adding an offset to the data data

Comment: You do not need to "destroy" your original *Month* column. You can save the "shifted date" in another column (e.g. *Month_wrk*) and then resample on just this column. Then you can drop this column.

Comment: I agree, and until know this is certainly the best solution for this problem. The only thing is that in my question I specifically asked for a solution that doesn't require to add an offset to the date since I already knew I could do it. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Not a working solution for OP's request. See short discussion in the comments.

Interesting problem. I suggest to resample using 'SMS' - semi-month start frequency (1st and 15th). Instead of keeping just the mean values, keep the count and sum values and recalculate the weighted mean for each monthly period by its two sub-period (for example: 15/1 to 15/2 is composed of 15/1-31/1 and 1/2-15/2).

The advantages here is that unlike with an (improper use of an) offset, we are certain we always start on the 15th of the month till the 14th of the next month.

```
df_sm = df.resample('SMS', on='Month').aggregate(['sum', 'count'])
df_sm

           Integers      
                sum count
Month                    
2018-01-01      876    16
2018-01-15      864    16
2018-02-01      412    10
2018-02-15      626    12
...
2018-12-01      492    10
2018-12-15      638    16
```

Rolling sum and rolling count; Find the mean out of them:

```
df_sm['sum_rolling'] = df_sm['Integers']['sum'].rolling(2).sum()
df_sm['count_rolling'] = df_sm['Integers']['count'].rolling(2).sum()
df_sm['mean'] = df_sm['sum_rolling'] / df_sm['count_rolling']

df_sm
           Integers       count_sum count_rolling       mean
                sum count                                   
Month                                                       
2018-01-01      876    16       NaN           NaN        NaN
2018-01-15      864    16    1740.0          32.0  54.375000
2018-02-01      412    10    1276.0          26.0  49.076923
2018-02-15      626    12    1038.0          22.0  47.181818
...
2018-12-01      492    10    1556.0          27.0  57.629630
2018-12-15      638    16    1130.0          26.0  43.461538
```

Now, just filter the odd indices of `df_sm`:

```
df_sm.iloc[1::2]['mean']

Month
2018-01-15    54.375000
2018-02-15    47.181818
2018-03-15    51.000000
2018-04-15    44.897436
2018-05-15    52.450000
2018-06-15    33.722222
2018-07-15    41.277778
2018-08-15    46.391304
2018-09-15    45.631579
2018-10-15    54.107143
2018-11-15    58.058824
2018-12-15    43.461538
Freq: 2SMS-15, Name: mean, dtype: float64
```

The code:

```
df_sm = df.resample('SMS', on='Month').aggregate(['sum', 'count'])
df_sm['sum_rolling'] = df_sm['Integers']['sum'].rolling(2).sum()
df_sm['count_rolling'] = df_sm['Integers']['count'].rolling(2).sum()
df_sm['mean'] = df_sm['sum_rolling'] / df_sm['count_rolling']
df_out = df_sm[1::2]['mean']
```

Edit: Changed a name of one of the columns to make it clearer

Comment: the idea is great. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I realize there is a mistake in your solution. The first row that is being print, with date  `2018-01-15` are actually summing dates from `2018-01-01` to `2018-01-31`. You could fix it by filtering the even indices, but then the first value will be NaN.

Comment: Sorry about that! I thought I checked it.. Just to make sure before I'll try to figure this out, you are passing 'SMS' and not 'SM' to `resample` right? I started with 'SM' and that's the exact reason I tried using 'SMS', thought it solved it..

Comment: Yep you are right. Can filter with `df_sm.iloc[::2]` and then Month '2018-02-01' corresponds to '2018-01-15' till '2018-02-14', and Month '2018-12-01' corresponds to '2018-11-15' till '2018-12-14'. But what are the requirements for the remaining half month in this year: '2018-01-01' till '2018-01-15' and '2018-12-15' till '2018-12-31'?

Comment: I saw no difference in using SM or SMS. The data before '2018-01-15' should be in an period starting from '2017-12-15'. I mean, the purpose is to use real data and not randon generated dates, but there will always be an initial date that I should guarantee it is in the right period. I believe the solution of using and offset of 14 days is the simplest solution. I was just expecting that the `origin` should work somehow for month resampling. It seems so stupid that it doesn't.

Comment: Using `.rolling(2, min_periods=1)` allows you to calculate the first period. However, the last one is not generated this way. Sorry.. I tried to add dummy data but seems like this is not going to make is more simple.